# how to distribute header across files

Tags: c++, header-files

**Edit For Clarification:**

**Is there a way to split a class's header across multiple files, such that other classes can include only the parts of that class's implementation it's supposed to be allowed to use?**

***----Below is specific details to my desired implementation:*---- NOT A NECESSARY READ!**

Anyways, I'm creating an entity-component system. I would like to structure it as follows:

There is an 'EntityPool' object that exists mainly as a memory store/manager for entities and their components. I would like to have a specified degree of access from my 'Game' class (for example, the ability to construct/destruct the pool, and the ability to access arrays of components ei the ability to iterate through all 'renderable' components).

There is a base class of 'EntityFactory' that I would like to have a greater degree of access to the entity pool. It would be used by the 'Game' class as follows:

```
GruntEntityFactory ef(&EntityPool); //GruntEntityFactory inherits from EntityFactory 
ef.produce();
```

The Entity Factory would then use its access to the Entity Pool to create the necessary components and put them in place.

The thing to note here is that 'Game' would have access only to create the EntityPool and read its contents, but would NOT be able to directly alter its contents. Everything that inherits EntityFactory, on the other hand, I would like to give access to manage EntityPool's contents.

**Is there a way I can include a different EntityPool header in each of the files, such that each is only 'aware' of the functions it has access to? Is that the best way to do this (assuming it's possible)?**

Also- I realize this tightly couples the EntityPool and EntityFactories. That is intentional. And also, I would like to not have to list every EntityFactory I make as a friend class in EntityPool.

Thanks!

**Example code for clarification**

```
//In my Game Class
#include "entitypool.h"
#include "entityfactory_grunt.h"

...

EntityPool ep(); //Construct an EntityPool
GruntEntityFactory gef(&ep); //Pass an EntityPool pointer to an EntityFactory
gef.produce(); //Call produce on GruntEntityFactory, and have it add appropriate components to the EntityPool

//I would like this next line to not be allowed. Game shouldn't be able to 
//directly manipulate the components/ other internal EntityPool structure.
//However, I WOULD like EntityFactories to retain the ability to do so.
//(otherwise, how would EntityFactory.produce() work?)
ep.addComponent(PhysicsComponent pc(1, 2, 3)); 

//I WOULD like Game to be able to access certain functions of EntityPool
for(int i = 0; i < ep.numPhysicsComponents; i++)//Like the count of entities
    physicsSolver.update(ep.physicsComponents[i]);//And the ability to update/render components
```

Ok. So hopefully that's sensible enough of an example to get an idea for what I want. The reason for the title is that my first intuition on how to achieve this would be to have 2 header files.

```
//EntityPool_GameAccess.h
//This file would contain prototypes for the functions utilized by Game, but NOT the ones
//that game is not allowed to see.

class EntityPool
{
    public:
        int numPhysicsComponents();
        PhysicsComponent getPhysicsComponent(int i);
};
```

and

```
//EntityPool_FactoryAccess.h
//This file would contain prototypes for the functions that only ought be used
//by classes specifically built to manipulate entitypool

class EntityPool
{
    public:
        void addPhysicsComponent(PhysicsComponent pc);
        int numPhysicsComponents();
        PhysicsComponent getPhysicsComponent(int i);
};
```

Obviously these examples are simplified. Hopefully I'm still getting the idea across: **I would like a class with certain functions that are accessible to certain classes, and other functions that are accessible to other classes.**

Comment: _'I'm not 100% sure the request in the title is what I want'_ At least for me it's unclear what you want to achieve. Edit your question to illustrate with some more code samples please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've updated my question with some examples. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: You say, "I would like a class with certain functions that are accessible to certain classes, and other functions that are accessible to other classes." That sounds like a bad design. It sounds like you have a god class that does too much. Perhaps what you need is a redesign? For example, a delegate that handles some of the functionality might be better. The delegate methods could then be in the delegate class's header file. (That's just one example. There are other design patterns that may be useful.)

Comment: @user1118321 actually, this is a result of me wanting to limit the scope of a class- NOT having a monolithic (god) class. The specific goal is to have a class that is more or less a dumb block of memory. I'd like that dumb class to ONLY be manipulatable by certain classes, but readable by others. I could solve this with a god class that simply adopts/implements the interface of all the classes I want to allow manipulation from, but I'd rather keep them separate.

Comment: Couldn't you create a struct with your data in it, and then have a reader class and a writer class? Then the reader can only read the data from the struct, and the writer could only write to the struct (or whatever the block would be).

Comment: Yes, but who would construct the struct? Although, it looks like something along these lines is what I'll end up doing. Not 100% ideal. Surprised this functionality doesn't exist in C++... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've finally found an answer in another question on StackOverflow: [Making classes public to other classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792614/making-classes-public-to-other-classes-in-c)

The bottom part of Patrick's answer:

> Unfortunately, there is no way in C++ to make only a part of your class public to a limited set of other classes.